# php can not connect to web services with the KPS

Tags: php, web

If I did not get rid of this error. How can I fix this error.

```
  $kPSServiceServis = new KPSServiceServis($wsdl);
    // sample call for KPSServiceServis::ServisUTCZamani()
    if($kPSServiceServis->ServisUTCZamani(new KPSTypeServisUTCZamani(/*** update parameters list ***/)))
        print_r($kPSServiceServis->getResult());
    else
        print_r($kPSServiceServis->getLastError());
```

Error message (wrapped for ease of reading):

```
Array ( [KPSServiceServis::ServisUTCZamani] => SoapFault Object (
    [message:protected] => Cannot process the message because the content type
                          'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type
                          'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
    [string:Exception:private] => ......

] =>  rate:KPSWsdlClass:private] =>
[internArrayToIterateIsArray:KPSWsdlClass:private] =>
[internArrayToIterateOffset:KPSWsdlClass:private] => ) ) ) ) 
[previous:Exception:private] => [faultstring] =>
    Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
    was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
[faultcode] => HTTP ) )
```

Comment: The webservice you're accessing is not sending the correct header content type. The error message is right there. Is it your own web service?

Comment: How to prevent this error, I need to define header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web service code given in c # and java. you think a win32 console application written with c #.

```
return shell_exec("KPS.exe" "username" "password" "parameters");
```

> KPS.exe  your user name, password, and give you the results that you
>   take based on the parameters will return an exe program.

then whether you use this application, you can parse the returned value.

https://kps.saglik.gov.tr/  links already existing codes